# Convert T-SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql

Is there an easy way to convert [Transact-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) to MySQL?

---

I am attempting to convert a database archive of stock ticker symbols and company names.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer: **NO**

The medium answer: **MAYBE**

The long answer: **That depends on what's in your TSQL and how much time and effort you want to put into it.**

TSQL is not a subset of MySQL's dialect. So there exists some TSQL for which there is no MySQL conversion. However, the overlap between the two languages is pretty significant, and to a certain degree the conversion is just a matter of syntax.

This isn't a new problem, and some people have tried to tackle it. A quick google search for "[tsql to mysql](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=tsql+to+mysql)" yields some promising results, notably this project here, which attempts to convert stored procedures from TSQL to MySQL:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tsql2mysql/

This probably won't solve your problem completely, but it's at least a start.

Comment: The short answer is no. The medium answer is no. The long answer is no. There is no easy way. Often, there simply is no way. They don't support the same feature set. Because of feature differences, the entire implementations could have to be radically different to achieve the same functionality. Locking hints and mechanisms critical to ordered blocking of operations are not the same. They're two completely different database technologies. They do similar things, but this is as asinine as thinking you could "easily" run a Mac Binary on Windows out of the box. No way.

Answer (score 5):

This website converts to/from many sql database versions:
http://www.sqlines.com/online

TSQL, MySql, Oracle, DB2, Sybase, Informix, Hive, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, RedShift, TeraData, Greenplum, Netezza

Comment: Sqlines is the best of the free tools I tried.  Not perfect, but gets you maybe 90% of the way there.  You can also download an offline version.

Answer (score 2):

Are the others say, it depends how long your particular piece of string is.

But, I would suggest that you do NOT want to convert Transact-SQL to MySQL.

If you think about it, I think that you will find that you want to convert it to [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odbc).

And then next year, when the company wants you to move it to Oracle, or Access ...

Answer (score 2):

I've just achieved a tsql script.

My solution is :

1. export table informations (schema pk)
2. export table data
3. export FK

I'm not very proud of my code, but it worked for me.

4 files wich are in the same folder:

Batch wich call sqlcmd

```
@echo off

set host= (local)
set schema=database
set user=user
set pass=pass

cd %cd%
rem tables 
SQLCMD -S %host% -d %schema% -U %user% -P %pass% -s "" -h-1 -W -i "%CD%\mysql_export_table.sql" -o "%CD%\%schema%_tables.sql" 
rem data
SQLCMD -S %host% -d %schema% -U %user% -P %pass% -s "" -h-1 -W -i "%CD%\mysql_export_data.sql" -o "%CD%\%schema%_data.sql" 
rem fk
SQLCMD -S %host% -d %schema% -U %user% -P %pass% -s "" -h-1 -W -i "%CD%\mysql_export_fk.sql" -o "%CD%\%schema%_fk.sql"
```

**then tsql script to export table schema mysql_export_table.sql**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
DECLARE @table_name as varchar(max)



DECLARE view_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Table_name FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and table_name not like 'sys%'

OPEN view_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM view_cursor 
INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


     select ''
     select '/*** TABLE '+@table_name+' ***/ '
     select 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name, '`') + ';'
     select ''
     select 'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name, '`') + ' ('

-- column declaration 

     select  
     CHAR(9)
+ QUOTENAME(Column_Name, '`') + ' ' +
DATA_TYPE
+
coalesce( '(' + cast(coalesce(replace(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, -1, 2500), null) as varchar) + ')', '')
+ ' ' +
case IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'NO' then 'NOT ' else '' end + 'NULL'
+ ' ' +
case when COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 then 'AUTO_INCREMENT' else '' end
--coalesce( 'DEFAULT ' + replace(replace(replace(COLUMN_DEFAULT, '(', ''), ')', ''), 'getdate', null), '')
+','
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @table_name
-- PK
select  coalesce('PRIMARY KEY (' +STUFF((
SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(Col.Column_Name,'`') from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab inner join  
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col  on Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
WHERE        
    Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY '
    AND Col.Table_Name = @table_name
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 1, '')+ ')', '') 

select ') Engine InnoDB;'

    FETCH NEXT FROM view_cursor 
    INTO @table_name
END 
CLOSE view_cursor;
DEALLOCATE view_cursor;
```

**then script for data  mysql_export_data.sql**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
DECLARE @table_name as varchar(max)
declare @column_names as varchar(max)


DECLARE view_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Table_name FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and table_name not like 'sys%'

OPEN view_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM view_cursor 
INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     select ''
     select '/*** TABLE '+@table_name+' ***/ '

     select @column_names = STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(Column_Name, '`') from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  Table_Name = @table_name  ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 1, '')

     select 'REPLACE INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@table_name, '`') +'('+ @column_names+ ') VALUES '
     select @column_names = 'SELECT DISTINCT ''('+ STUFF(( SELECT ', '','''''' + coalesce(replace(cast(' + QUOTENAME(Column_Name)  +' as varchar(200)), '''''''',''''), '''') + ''''''''' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  Table_Name = @table_name  ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') , 1, 4, '') + '+''),'' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
     exec (@column_names)

    FETCH NEXT FROM view_cursor 
    INTO @table_name
END 
CLOSE view_cursor;
DEALLOCATE view_cursor;
```

Finally FK script

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
-- FK
-- foreign keys
SELECT 
     'ALTER TABLE',
     ' '+ QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkcol.[object_id]), '`'),
--ADD CONSTRAINT `recherche_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`notaire_compte_id`) REFERENCES `notaire_compte` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
    ' ADD CONSTRAINT',
    ' ' + QUOTENAME(fk.name, '`'), 
    ' FOREIGN KEY',
    ' (' + QUOTENAME(fkcol.name, '`') +')',
    ' REFERENCES',    
    ' ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(pkcol.[object_id]), '`'),
    ' (' + QUOTENAME(pkcol.name, '`') + ');',
    CHAR(13)

FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
ON fk.[object_id] = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS fkcol
ON fkc.parent_object_id = fkcol.[object_id]
AND fkc.parent_column_id = fkcol.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pkcol
ON fkc.referenced_object_id = pkcol.[object_id]
AND fkc.referenced_column_id = pkcol.column_id
ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id;
```

I know, i know...  it's very ugly ...

**The goal of this script is not to convert TSQL to Mysql but to export database from MSSQL to Mysql**

On the table result you'll have to execute a regex replace (notepad++)
replace ",\r\n\r\n)" by "\r\n\r\n)"

On the data result replace ",\r\n\r\n/*" by ";\r\n\r\n/*"

Execution order : Table -> Data -> FK

Comment: So, this basically proves @tylerl's short answer so far, as far as I can see. Although your posting this may in fact have invalidated it (if this solution works out well for many people, that is).

Answer (score 1):

How about using SQL Server Linked Servers ? You can SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE data from MySQL using TSQL