# Best Way to move an Existing MsSQL database to MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, database-schema

Whats the best method and or tools to move a MsSQL database to MySQL ?

Please be as literal as possible as I have limited experience with databases and next to none with moving them.

Comment: check structure! check if all needed data types are represented in both RDBMS. check if there are UDF or SP in MSSQL which have to be rewritten manually. check if there are triggers...

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279303/how-to-convert-mssql-database-to-mysql-database and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770795/convert-mysql-script-to-mssql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL itself offers a Migration Toolkit, which - in my experience - works rather well, not only with SQL-Server, and is as easy as it can get.

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html