# a best tool to copy data from mssql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to change an application from mssql to mysql.

So I have to copy all of existing data from mssql to mysql. I need a sufficient tool for this.

Which tool would be best for doign so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=copy+data+from+mssql+to+mysql hope it helps.

Comment: Hope this post wpuld help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-ms-sql-database-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SQL Server Import and Export Wizard http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187710.aspx

SQL Server Integration Services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Answer (score -1):

In my case I move mssql database to access and then from access to mysql using free tool http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php.

I've just wrote an article on my blog about that, you can find it http://blog.koko.ge/?p=22.

Answer (score -2):

1.Open SQL Server Management Studio on your local machine.
2.Right click the Databases folder. From the pop-up menu, select New Database.
3.Enter a database name, and then click Ok.
4.Right click the new database icon. From the pop-up menu, select Tasks -> Restore -> Database.
5.Select the From Device option, and then click the browse button.
6.Click Add and navigate to the appropriate file. Click Ok.
7.In the Restore Database window, select the checkbox next to your BAK file.
8.Switch to the Options page. Select the Overwrite the existing database checkbox. Click Ok.
9. Verify the contents of your database, which is now active on your local machine.

Comment: To avoid any confusion, the instructions above will move database from one instance of MS SQL Server to another instance of MS SQL Server. You cannot move data from MSSQL to MySQL this way.