# MS SQL Studio .bak to PHPmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux, phpmyadmin

I have a client that needs me to transfer their website from a MS server to my linux server. Their website was built with PHP, but the database is in MS SQL Studio. I need to get the database into a formate that will import into PHPMyAdmin. I've got the .bak file. But I don't know how to convert it into something I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the complexity and size of the schema, you’re going to need to restore the .bak file to an MS SQL Server instance (you can use the free express version if the database is less than 4GB) then use a conversion tool such as DBConvert to migrate the schema and data to mysql.

This is not an exact science though; if your data is complex (I.e. CLR datatypes such as geography) or very t-sql (i.e. stored procedure) you may have trouble depending on the target version of your mysql box. For example - I think mysql 5 is required for stored procedures.

If you dont want to use a 3rd party product such as DBConvert, you can use the tools provided by mysql, the main one being the migration toolkit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/

Related question:

[How to export SQL Server database to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-ms-sql-database-to-mysql)

Comment: From - http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/migration/

"Please note that development of MySQL Migration Toolkit has been discontinued. MySQL Workbench provides and integrated GUI environment for MySQL database design, SQL development, administration and migration."

The link above provides download links to the discontinued migration toolkit, however I'd recommend using the MySQL workbench.

(I know I'm commenting on a 3 year old post, but my Google search led me directly here, so I'm just trying to help the next person who gets sent here.)