# Is it possible to Connecting MYsql with sql server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I am using an open source software which support mysql and i create application that uses asp.net 4.0 and sql server 2008....

Is it possible to Connecting MYsql with sql server ?

I want every insertion and updating should be made to both database servers as they have same schema of tables but one is mysql and other is sql server 2008 ?

kindly explain step by step if possible

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Use a windows service to synchronize both. I've done the same few weeks ago. Edit: Although when both have the same schema you could also link them: http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-ms-sql-database-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help,this shows step by step connection

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29106/Migrate-MySQL-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use linked server in MS SQL Server.

From the documentation - *A linked server allows for access to distributed, heterogeneous queries against OLE DB data sources.*

Have a look at [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) function.