# how to export or import sql server database from sql server to mysql server through network

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to connect mysql server system from mssql sever system through network because I want to import or export sql server database from mssql server system to mysql server system.

can anybody tell me that how can I do this?

thanks

Comment: Below link will be helpful

[How to export MS SQL database to MYSQL?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-ms-sql-database-to-mysql

Comment: There is already answer here in StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-ms-sql-database-to-mysql/11792893#11792893

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this script, which allows you to import data. You must specify the table name and run the generated code on your MySQL server.

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE Labour.Employee 
(
      EmployeeID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    , IsMainWorkPlace BIT NOT NULL
    , TabelNumber VARCHAR(6) NULL
    , PersonID INT NOT NULL
    , DepartmentUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
    , DateIn DATETIME NOT NULL
    , DateOut DATETIME NULL
    , PositionID INT NULL
    , DatePension DATETIME NULL
    , IsLabourUnionMember BIT NOT NULL
    , FiringReasonID INT NULL
)
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE 
      @Table NVARCHAR(50)
    , @Schema NVARCHAR(50)
    , @ObjectID INT
    , @IsImportIdentity BIT = 1
    , @IsCreateTable BIT = 1

DECLARE [tables] CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
SELECT 
      t.name
    , s.name
    , t.[object_id]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
          t.[schema_id]
        , t.[object_id]
        , t.name
    FROM sys.tables t WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.partitions p WITH (NOWAIT) ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
    WHERE p.[rows] > 0
) t
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE t.name IN ('<your table>')

OPEN [tables]

FETCH NEXT FROM [tables] INTO 
      @Table
    , @Schema
    , @ObjectID

DECLARE 
      @Name SYSNAME = N''
    , @NewName SYSNAME = N''
    , @SQLCreate NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
    , @SQLInsert NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
    , @SQLColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
    , @SQLTinyColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT 
          @Name = @Schema + N'.' + @Table
        , @NewName = N'`' + LOWER(@Schema) + N'`.`' + LOWER(@Table) + N'`'
        , @SQLCreate = N''
        , @SQLInsert = N''
        , @SQLColumns = N''
        , @SQLTinyColumns = N''

    SELECT 
          @SQLCreate = N'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + @NewName + N';' + CHAR(13) +
            N'CREATE TABLE ' + @NewName + CHAR(13) + N'(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
            SELECT CHAR(9) + N', `' + 
                c.name + N'` ' + CASE WHEN t.name = N'uniqueidentifier' THEN 'VARCHAR(36)' ELSE UPPER(t.name) END + 
                CASE WHEN t.name IN (N'nvarchar', N'varchar', N'nchar', N'char', N'varbinary', N'binary')
                       THEN N'(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN N'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS NVARCHAR(5)) END + N')'
                     WHEN t.name IN (N'datetime2', N'time2', N'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN N'(' + CAST(c.scale AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N')'
                     WHEN t.name = N'decimal' 
                       THEN N'(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N',' + CAST(c.scale AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N')'
                    ELSE N''
                END + N' ' +  
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 0 THEN N'NOT NULL' ELSE N'DEFAULT NULL' END + N' ' +  
                CASE WHEN c.is_identity = 1 THEN N'AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY' ELSE N'' END
                  + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.columns c
            JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.system_type_id = t.user_type_id
            WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + N' ') + N');'
        , @SQLInsert = N'INSERT INTO ' + @NewName + N' (' + STUFF((
            SELECT N', `' + c.name + '`'
            FROM sys.columns c
            WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
                AND (c.is_identity = 0 OR @IsImportIdentity = 1)
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, N'') + N')'
        , @SQLTinyColumns = STUFF((
            SELECT N', ' + c.name
            FROM sys.columns c
            WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, N'')
        , @SQLColumns = STUFF((SELECT + CHAR(13) +
            CASE 
                WHEN t.name = N'uniqueidentifier' 
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CAST([' + c.name + '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                WHEN t.name IN (N'nvarchar', N'varchar', N'nchar', N'char', N'varbinary', N'binary') 
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CAST(REPLACE([' + c.name + '], '''''''', '''''''''''' ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                WHEN t.name = N'datetime'
                    THEN ' + '', '' + ISNULL('''''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [' + c.name + '], 120) + '''''''', ''NULL'')' 
                ELSE 
                N' + '', '' + ISNULL(CAST([' + c.name + '] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), N''NULL'')'
            END
            FROM sys.columns c
            JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.system_type_id = t.user_type_id
            WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
                AND (c.is_identity = 0 OR @IsImportIdentity = 1)
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N'root[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 10, N'CHAR(13) + '', ('' +')
    FROM sys.objects o 
    WHERE o.[type] IN (N'V', N'U')
        AND o.object_id = @ObjectID

    IF @IsCreateTable = 1
        PRINT @SQLCreate
    ELSE
        PRINT N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @NewName + N';'

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE 
          @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''''
        , @x INT = 1
        , @count INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' + @Name + ')

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#import'')
    )
        DROP TABLE #import;

    SELECT *, ''RowNumber'' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @SQLTinyColumns + N')
    INTO #import
    FROM ' + @Name + N' 

    WHILE @x < @count BEGIN

        SELECT @SQL = ''VALUES '' + STUFF((
        SELECT ' + @SQLColumns + N' + '')''' + N'
        FROM #import 
        WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @x AND @x + 9
        FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE, ROOT).value(N''root[1]'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, CHAR(13) + '' '') + '';''

        PRINT(''' + @SQLInsert + ''')
        PRINT(@SQL)

        SELECT @x = @x + 10

    END'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM [tables] INTO 
          @Table
        , @Schema
        , @ObjectID

END

CLOSE [tables]
DEALLOCATE [tables]
```

**Output:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `labour`.`employee`;
CREATE TABLE `labour`.`employee`
(
      `EmployeeID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , `IsMainWorkPlace` BIT NOT NULL 
    , `TabelNumber` VARCHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL 
    , `PersonID` INT NOT NULL 
    , `DepartmentUID` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL 
    , `DateIn` DATETIME NOT NULL 
    , `DateOut` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL 
    , `PositionID` INT DEFAULT NULL 
    , `DatePension` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL 
    , `IsLabourUnionMember` BIT NOT NULL 
    , `FiringReasonID` INT DEFAULT NULL 
);
INSERT INTO `labour`.`employee` (`EmployeeID`, `IsMainWorkPlace`, `TabelNumber`, `PersonID`, `DepartmentUID`, `DateIn`, `DateOut`, `PositionID`, `DatePension`, `IsLabourUnionMember`, `FiringReasonID`)
VALUES 
  (165515, 0, '65515', 183994, '9DA9EEC9-F2EC-4FC7-8F21-DF646FDF397E', '1994-03-06 00:00:00', NULL, 35125, '2001-05-01 00:00:00', 1, NULL)
, (165516, 1, '65516', 184184, '9DA9EEC9-F2EC-4FC7-8F21-DF646FDF397E', '1994-12-09 00:00:00', NULL, 35125, NULL, 1, NULL)
, (165517, 1, '65517', 185214, '0BF3F7C4-2590-40D0-880D-923C8D8339A7', '1953-11-02 00:00:00', '2002-10-05 00:00:00', 35125, '1974-08-06 00:00:00', 1, NULL)
, (165518, 1, '65518', 185536, '2CE8E026-FE5B-4BDD-9330-43AB43CE3DE0', '2004-07-12 00:00:00', '2004-12-01 00:00:00', 35129, '2003-08-06 00:00:00', 0, NULL)
, (165519, 1, '65519', 185596, '2CE8E026-FE5B-4BDD-9330-43AB43CE3DE0', '2004-11-17 00:00:00', NULL, 35129, NULL, 0, NULL)
, (165520, 1, '65520', 184912, '0BF3F7C4-2590-40D0-880D-923C8D8339A7', '1988-10-22 00:00:00', '2003-03-05 00:00:00', 35120, NULL, 1, NULL)
, (165521, 1, '65521', 184984, '1D07CF00-A7FA-489D-9D58-286C7E24A7A2', '2001-04-06 00:00:00', NULL, 35120, NULL, 1, NULL)
, (165522, 1, '65522', 185008, '896681F3-B452-410E-AD4A-97DCF4FE6722', '1994-05-11 00:00:00', NULL, 35120, NULL, 1, NULL)
, (165523, 0, '65523', 183993, 'DC5106A4-3649-4C12-ABF5-03CE21EC1679', '1994-05-06 00:00:00', NULL, 35124, NULL, 1, NULL)
, (165524, 1, '65524', 184146, 'A603E966-6F85-4FC1-BA06-40E391C7218E', '1995-03-22 00:00:00', NULL, 35111, NULL, 1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [Data Loader](http://www.dbload.com/)

Comment: Trial version of this tool has a some limitation when you export data.