# sql server table relationships to port to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, relational-database, database-migration

I ported a MS SQL 2008 database to MYSQL using a tool (NaviCAT). All the tables ported OK and the data seemed intact.

But now I am implementing a project using that MySQL database and I noticed that all the table relationships where gone.

Anyone knows how I can port a MS SQL database to MySQL without losing the table relationships or if there is a way to just port the relationships?.

Comment: This answer will help you. There is are may tools to do it. Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-ms-sql-database-to-mysql

Comment: Did the generated DDL script contain the foreign key definitions? If yes, did you make sure you are using InnoDB as your storage engine? All others will simply ignore any foreign key reference (and InnoDB for some syntax flavors)

Comment: yeah It was the InnoDB option. It worked when I reported the MSSQL database last night. All the relationships are there and I can see them in the .sql generated.  Thanks!