# MySQL - Import a SQL Server 2008 database script generated

Tags: mysql

I have generated a 20Mb SQL script of a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with the function Generate Script with Schema and Data (INSERT INTO included).
I'd like to re-generate the database in a MySQL host on a CentOS 5.8 platform and so I tried with phpMyAdmin which has the MSSQL compatibility's import function, but it was trying to load the file then server closed the phpMyAdmin connection without a particular reason....

Is there a possible way to generate in a MySQL 5.5 host a new database from a SQL Server 2008 R2 .sql script?

Thanks in advance to everyone...
Cheers!
Luigi

Comment: I'd import the file using "mysql < filename.sql" so you can see the error. Obviously you won't get the PMA compat stuff there though.

Comment: First, thank you dwjv for replying... I also exported the database selecting the option 'Script for Server Version' as 'SQL Server 2005'... would that help a bit about importing into MySQL ?

Comment: I doubt it. That's just an older version of SQL Server. Check out this post, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-ms-sql-database-to-mysql