# How to get data from multiple MS SQL and append it in MySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me reiterate,
I have 4 mssql databases, located remotely. I have to design a utility that should extract the data from all 4 databases and should update/append in one table which is in mysql server. This should be handled by a scheduler. How to achieve this?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want to move all data from the MSSQL databases you choose to MYSQL? I'm thinking that SSIS might be an option if you want to run it every day over a long period of time.
There's also something called http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ which seems to be a possible option. I haven't used it though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export SQL Server database to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-sql-server-database-to-mysql)

Comment: I have specifically mentioned "to append the selected data", which is possible either using Views or procedure. Also it is not one time process. Rather I want to schedule that runs daily and append the incremental data.