# Import table values into mysql

Tags: mysql

I have few tables with datas in SQL and I have created same tables in MySQL. I want to import the table data's from SQL table to respective MySQL table .Is there a simple way?Please help.Thank you

Comment: Hi there. First of all, what you mean by "few tables with datas in SQL"? SQL is just the query language, Is it another database? Perhaps SQLServer? If this is the case there are some possible ways, but you need to provide more details, servers OS are the databases in different machine or the same machine?

Comment: And if this is the case, your question is just a duplicate of many others eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-sql-server-database-to-mysql