# sql server to google spanner migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

right now i am using microsoft sql server for my database in my dev app. in future if i want to migrate my database in google spanner what guidelines should i follow from right now so then migration should be easy in feature. also does google provide any migration tools like Microsoft® Data Migration Assistant.

```
SYNOPSIS
gcloud spanner instances create INSTANCE --config=CONFIG
    --description=DESCRIPTION --nodes=NODES [--async] [GLOBAL-FLAG ...]
```

does spanner has any local emulator so i can install it in my local machine and test it before

```
gcloud spanner instances create --help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud spanner is Google's **horizontally scalable** relational database. It is [quite expensive](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/pricing)(running it in minimal configuration with 3 nodes would cost you at least 100$ daily). Unless you really need the horizontal scalability you should use Cloud SQL.

Cloud SQL is a managed MySQL or PostgreSQL service by Google. You can migrate your data to Cloud SQL easily as this is a common use case. How you do it depends on your choice. For example check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-sql-server-database-to-mysql) question for exporting it to MySql. You can check [this link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL) to convert to PostgreSQL.

Check the Google's decision tree if you are unfamiliar with the details of Google's storage options:

[image]

Comment: Note: with 3 nodes in us-central1 at current pricing, [nodes: 0.9 ($/node/hour) *3 (nodes) *24 (hour/day)] + [storage: 6 (2TiB per node)*1024(GiB/TiB)*0.3/30 ($/GiB/day)] +network. 0.9*3*24+6*1024*0.3/30 = [$64.8~$126.24+network]