# SQL MDF (extension file) to MariaDB - How to migrate SQL MDF File to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I am having issues with MariaDB and cannot find resources on how to open a .MDF file (Contains SQL DB Data, correct me if I'm wrong) using MariaDB. I have found some third-party software such as https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-mdf-to-mariadb-online which converted the file, but you have to pay for the entire migration of data. I have also read the documentation for MariaDB and it seems to only support .CSV files, schemas aren't' supported in MariaDB, and alternate is doing a dump (not sure if this will work). I'm highly new with to SQL and MariaDB with practically no knowledge so please don't scold me, thanks!

Comment: restore the sql server and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-sql-server-database-to-mysql

Comment: They are completely incompatible DB engines with many different features. Except for the most rudimentary of databases it won't be an easy task. Why do you even want to migrate your DB engine?