# How To Restore .mdf File After Backup C#

Tags: c#, sql, database-restore, mdf

How to restore a database from a `.mdf`?

I wrote a `.mdf` to `.bak` method and the code worked correctly
but when I wrote a restore method it did not work.

My code:

```cs
private void restoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Filter = "نسخة احتياطية من قاعدة البيانات|*.bak";
        op.Title = "اختر مكان النسخة الاحتياطية";
        // op.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("[yyyy-dd-M]-[HH-mm-ss]" + "  " + "  " + "نسخة بتاريخ");

        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (SqlConnection Sql_Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string file = string.Format("backup database [" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Car_Database] to disk='{0}'", op.FileName);
                string constring = "server=localhost;port3306;user=root;pwd=root;Car_Database=sms; Convert zero Datatime=true;";
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                    {
                        using (MySqlBackup mbak = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = conn;
                            Sql_Conn.Open();
                            mbak.ImportFromFile(file);
                            Sql_Conn.Close();

                            MessageBox.Show("تمت عملة النسخ بنجاح");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("عذراً . لقد حدث خطأ ما اثناء قيامك بعمل نسخة من قاعدة البيانات , الرجاء المحاولة مرة اخرة");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception message do you get?

Comment: SqlConnection is for Microsoft SQL Server, MySqlConnection is for Oracle's MySQL (and perhaps MariaDB), you can't just backup and restore between them.

Comment: what the Slove????

Comment: Are you sure you know which database product you are using? You appear to be confused between SQL Server and MySQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export SQL Server database to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-sql-server-database-to-mysql)

Comment: **An `.mdf` file is not a backup** - it's a _live_ database file (though probably in a detached state). You can certianly try to attach it but you also need the `.ldf` file too (the `.ldf` is the Transaction Log file, the `.mdf` is everything else). SQL Server backups typically have a `.bak` extension and you can mount them to look-inside.

Comment: i'm using local sql database