# How to convert TSQL query into MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have developed a function for split string in tsql but mysql don't have some built in functions. I needed to function in MYSQL as i am new in mysql. Function should accept 2 parameters
  1. String to be split
 2. separator (',' or whatever)
Kindly reply me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert tsql to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986404/convert-tsql-to-mysql)

Comment: You can use `SUBSTRING(@orig, LOCATE(@findstr, @orig))`

Comment: What is the output of your T-SQL "split string" function? We can easily write a MySQL function that accepts two parameters. The hard part is emulating what your SQL Server "split string" function does.

Comment: I am trying to add the sql server code not succeeded i am new in stackover flow community ;9

Comment: so i added an answer can you help @spencer7593

Comment: @alex-gidan read the description will understand you the question level, it is not about converting any mysql to tsql it is about for spliting function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had found solution on the internet you can into that.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `splitAndTranslate` //
CREATE FUNCTION splitAndTranslate(str TEXT, delim VARCHAR(124))
RETURNS TEXT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;    -- total number of delimiters
    DECLARE ctr INT DEFAULT 0;  -- counter for the loop
    DECLARE str_len INT;        -- string length,self explanatory
    DECLARE out_str text DEFAULT '';    -- return string holder
    DECLARE temp_str text DEFAULT '';   -- temporary string holder
    DECLARE temp_val VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';   -- temporary string holder for query

    -- get length
    SET str_len=LENGTH(str);    

    SET i = (LENGTH(str)-LENGTH(REPLACE(str, delim, '')))/LENGTH(delim) + 1;    
        -- get total number delimeters and add 1
        -- add 1 since total separated values are 1 more than the number of delimiters

    -- start of while loop
    WHILE(ctr<i) DO
        -- add 1 to the counter, which will also be used to get the value of the string
        SET ctr=ctr+1; 

        -- get value separated by delimiter using ctr as the index
        SET temp_str = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, ctr), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim,ctr - 1)) + 1), delim, '');

        -- query real value and insert into temporary value holder, temp_str contains the exploded ID           
        SELECT <real_value_column> INTO temp_val FROM <my_table> WHERE <table_id>=temp_str;

        -- concat real value into output string separated by delimiter
            SET out_str=CONCAT(out_str, temp_val, ',');
    END WHILE;
    -- end of while loop

    -- trim delimiter from end of string
    SET out_str=TRIM(TRAILING delim FROM out_str);
    RETURN(out_str);    -- return 

END//
```

reference http://www.slickdev.com/2008/09/15/mysql-query-real-values-from-delimiter-separated-string-ids/

Comment: thanks for help -@ehtasham i will lookinto that then will let you know about it

Answer (score 0):

In mysql they they dont support some functionality like sqlserver. so spliting will be difficult in mysql

```
SELECT e.`studentId`, SPLIT(",", c.`courseNames`)[e.`courseId`]
```

FROM ..

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourcolumn,',',1)), TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourcolumn,',',-1)) FROM yourtable
```

Comment: If `yourcolumn` contains more than one separator character (comma in this example), the first expression will return the portion of the string up to the first separator, and the second expression will return the portion of the string following the last separator. For example, given `'abc,def,ghi'`, the first expression returns `'abc'`, the second expression returns `'ghi'`.

Comment: it takes time but this is a solution so i have to go into lop for the length of the string and then set the index . but now part is that how to use loop in the mysql query @Ehtasham

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
(
    @RowData nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    --Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END
```

Comment: it returns all the values like rows and i can use it in where clause. But i needed it in mysql. i tried alot googling it and by myslef, but did not succeeded yet