# How and where should I run a SQL script with GO statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have been given the script bellow and I honestly do no know how to run it.
I have never seen this kind of syntax before. Please assist. I tried importing it with php my admin and I just got syntax errors

```
USE [AppDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Person]    Script Date: 2018/11/12 4:48:10 PM 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
[PersonId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: It does not look like MySQL. Please retag the question with appropriate RDBMS you are using

Comment: The name of the file that contains the script is : schema.sql. I was given the script an instructed to use to create a local DB with it.

Comment: Please post the syntax errors. (to me it looks like MSSQL script but that is just guessing) Also: if you do not know what this is and what you should be doing, wouldn't it make more sense to ask the one that gave the script to you for help and clarification?

Comment: If you are assigned a task for which you are unqualified, do not just say "OK" and go ask strangers on the internet. Ask the person who assigned the task; there are too many unknowns here. In which server instance should you do this? Does the database named AppDB already exist? Do you have permissions to run this type of script? What permissions should be granted? If an error occurs, what should you do? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 100% a SQL Server script.

The easiest way to run it is through SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which you can download from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).

You're also missing the rest of the CREATE TABLE statement.

You'll also need a running SQL Server instance to run it against.

Alternatively you could use [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to run it.

Also, if you're looking to run this in ASP.Net then you can follow [these](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/manishkdwivedi/create-table-at-run-time-in-database-by-using-Asp-Net/) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Phpmyadmin is for MySQL in general. The code above is in SQL server.

You have to translate SQL server to MySQL. `GO` is only the end of statement in Microsoft SQL tools, in other IDE you could replace it by `;`.

To translate the best is to separate commands, for example in `Create Table` separate FK and PK.

`Use`,`set` are specifics to Mssql.

Read that for more information [Convert T-SQL to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986404/convert-t-sql-to-mysql)